# API call directly from Design Automation Activity

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am trying to follow DA tutorial to extract data from CAD file and post the data to a web api. Probably I can extract and save a data file in OSS( or somewhere temporarily, I haven't figured out yet), and use my web app to read this file before sending the api request. Instead of this double handling, is it legal to call API directly from Activities? Same like a plug-in in laptop, it programs a local file and then sends a HTTP call.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> is it legal to call API directly from Activities? Same like a plug-in in laptop, it programs a local file and then sends a HTTP call.

Currently it is not possible to send Http requests from within Appbundle code, this is something our Engineering team researching.